# React wont update state on useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new  in react. can anyone explain why the loading is not updating its value. on console the loading is 1

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    function App() {
        useEffect(() => {
            hai();
        }, []);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(1);
    
        const hai = () => {
            console.log("............");
            setLoading(2);
            console.log(loading);
        };
    
        return <></>;
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Also if there are two state variables, and rearrange the set function, whole application breaks

```
const [loading, setLoading]=useState(false)
const [datas, setDatas]=useState([])

//works fine if loading is set second
 const hai = () => {
       setDatas(res) //fetched from external api
       setLoading(true) 

  };
//throws error in applicaton
 const hai = () => {
       setLoading(true) 
       setDatas(res) //fetched from external api
 };


console.log(datas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing your loading value in a wrong way,this is how you should be doing it:

```
useEffect(() => {
            console.log(loading);
        }, [loading]);
```

and remove console.log(loading) from the function hai
Whenever you want to access an updated value of some variable then put it inside an useEffect and put the value which you want to check inside the useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: can you explain why the loading variable is not updating inside function and works in useEffect? Does the component needs to be rendered in order to show its update its value?

Comment: @martin As [set state in react are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for performance reason, so logging it right after setting it : `setLoading(2); console.log(loading);` shows you old state data.